# Using Flux with structs: unexpected channel dimension

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I seem to be getting different behaviour (different output dimensions) when calling Flux functions in a struct, versus directly applying the functions to a tensor:

Direct application:

```
m = Chain(MaxPool((2,2), stride=2),Conv((3,3), 32*8=>32*16, pad=1), BatchNorm(32*16, relu),Conv((3,3), 32*16=>32*16, pad=1), BatchNorm(32*16, relu))
println(size(m(ones((32, 32, 256, 1))))) #gives the expected (16, 16, 512, 1)
```

Via a struct:

```
block(in_channels, features) = Chain(MaxPool((2,2), stride=2), Conv((3,3), in_channels=>features, pad=1), BatchNorm(features, relu), Conv((3,3), features=>features, pad=1), BatchNorm(features, relu))

struct test
    b
end

function test()
    b = (block(32*8, 32*16))
    test(b)
end

function (t::test)(x)
    x1 = t.b[1](x)
    println(size(x1)) 
end

test1 = test()
test1(ones((32, 32, 256, 1))) #gives (16, 16, 256, 1)
```

Why is the output channel dimensions different for the 2 snippets? What am I missing about structs in Julia? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to define the `(t::test)(x)` function would be

```
function (t::test)(x)
    x1 = t.b(x)  # Note the absence of [1]
    println(size(x1)) 
end
```

`t.b[1]` would give the first layer in Chain, i.e., `MaxPool((2, 2), pad = (0, 0, 0, 0), stride = (2, 2))` and as such your input is never passed through the Conv Layers.

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake, it's related to indexing instead of use of structs. I declared `b` as `b = (block(32*8, 32*16))`, but by indexing `b[1]`, I am actually only calling the first operation (`MaxPool`) in the Flux chain, which accounts for the difference in channel dimension. What I should do instead is `b = block(32*8, 32*16)` and `x1 = t.b(x)` to run all functions in the chain.